# Выравнивание текста в QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, qtextedit

У меня стоит задача прочесть файл, состоящий из текста, поделенного на несколько абзацев, и вывести его в какой-нибудь виджет. Например, QTextEdit. Хочется выравнять все, а получается только один абзац.

```
{
ui->setupUi(this);
QFile file("./result");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
qDebug() << "Ошибка при открытии файла";
QTextStream in(&file);
QString string;
string = in.readAll(); //Вывод в текстовое поле содержимое читаемого файла
ui->tE->setText(string);
ui->tE->setAlignment(Qt::AlignJustify);
file.close();
QFile("./result").remove(); }
```

Может, есть какой-нибудь другой способ выравнивания или лучше использовать какой-нибудь другой виджет?

Answer (score 1):

Не вполне понятно, какого поведения от виджета вы ожидаете. `QTextEdit` - редактор текста а-ля ворд. Т.е. со спецификацией выравнивания для каждого параграфа, и с выбором стиля символов (цвета, шрифта, подчеркивания,...) для любого фрагмента текста. Если все это вам нужно, то стиль выравнивания следует установить для всего текста:

```
    auto cursor = ui->tE->textCursor();
    ui->tE->selectAll();
    ui->tE->setAlignment(Qt::AlignJustify);
    ui->tE->setTextCursor( cursor ); // undo change selection
```

При этом, например, copy-paste из форматированного документа, будет копировать и форматирование, включае выравнивание абзацев.

Если все это богатство ненужно, а нужен "просто текст", то следует использовать `QPlainTextEdit`, но красивого (`AlignJustify`) выравнивания абзацев в нем не предусмотрено. Максиму, что возможно - настроить правила переноса слов.

```
ui->tE->setLineWrapMode(QPlainTextEdit::WidgetWidth);
ui->tE->setWordWrapMode(QTextOption::WrapAtWordBoundaryOrAnywhere);
```